# Subjonctif après l'expression d'une recherche

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

J'ai trouvé ces trois explications sur le subjonctif avec des verbes de recherche ou demande... Dans la deuxième explication est écrit qu'on utilise le subjonctif avec un/une et en fait dans tous les examples il y a un "un". Mais dans la phrase: "Je connais quelqu'un qui sait/sache parler espagnol." Est-ce qu'on utilise le subjonctif ?
Selon la deuxième explication oui, selon 1 et 3 non. Et est-qu'on a besoin toujours d'un "un/une" dans ce style des phrase, parce que ce n'est pas mentionné dans les explications 1 et 3.?

1. Après l'expression d'un désir, d'une demande ou d'une recherche

L'idée de demande, de recherche est exprimée par:

1. des verbes comme chercher, vouloir...
2. la forme interrogative

p.e. Il cherche une secrétaire qui sache parfaitement l'anglais. (desir)

p.e. - Connais-tu un hôtel qui soit calme ? (désir)

p.e. Y a-t-il parmi vous quelqu'un qui sache parler le coréen ? (demande)

2. subjonctif dans une subordonnée relative en fonction de l'antécedant
   antécédent précédé d'un indéfini:un/une

p.e. Je cherche **une** personne qui sait le français.

p.e. je cherche **une** personne qui sache le français.

3. On met aussi au subjonctif le verbe de la proposition subordonnée après des pronoms relatifs qui ne sont précédés d'aucune expression marquant le superlatif, la négation ou une petite quantité, lorsqu'on veut indiquer quelque chose de douteux.

p.e. Montrez-moi un chemin qui conduit au bonheur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu dis :

> Mais dans la phrase: "Je connais quelqu'un qui sait/sache parler
>   espagnol." Est-ce qu'on utilise le subjonctif ? Selon la deuxième
>   explication oui, selon 1 et 3 non.

Les critères que tu cites (dits sémantico-syntaxiques) ne fonctionnent pas en ET. Il fonctionnent en OU.
C'est à dire que tu n'as pas besoin que les trois critères soient vérifiés pour **pouvoir** mettre un subjonctif. Un seul d'entre-eux suffit.

=> OUI, dans ta phrase, tu **peux** conjuguer savoir au subjonctif. (Selon la valeur que tu souhaites conférer à *savoir*.)

Ce qui, je pense, répond à ta question suivante :

> est-qu'on a besoin toujours d'un "un/une" dans ce style des phrase,
>   parce que ce n'est pas mentionné dans les explications 1 et 3.?

Comme un seul des critères est nécessaire, la réponse est donc :
Non! on n'a pas toujours besoin d'un article indéfini dans ce style de phrase.

Attention : En tout état de cause, les règles que tu as citées correspondent à des cas généraux.
Et le verbe *savoir* est vraiment particulier car il supporte volontiers le subjonctif dans une foule d'autres circonstances qui surprennent parfois même un auditeur natif.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour l'explication. Est-ce que tu peux citer un exemple où on n'a pas besoin d'un article indéfini dans ce style de phrase?

Comment: @Katharina : Dans un contexte de recherche / demande donc : "*J'ai demandé que tu **sois** applaudie.*" - "*J'attends, je demande, j'exige qu'on me **comprenne** bien*' ...

Comment: Ou encore dans le style demande + COD + relative : "* Je ne recherche rien qu'on ne **puisse** trouver ici.*"

Answer (score 1):

Le subjonctif est un temps assez peu utilisé en français, beaucoup plus  à l'écrit. Dans ton exemple "Je connais quelqu'un qui sait/sache parler espagnol.", j'utiliserais plutôt le présent simple ("sait") car il reflète une capacité propre à cette personne de parler couramment l'espagnol.

Mais pour le besoin d'avoir un "un/une", c'est totalement faux : prenons exemple "Qu'il sache ou non parler espagnol, il pourra m'aider grandement au Mexique" est une phrase tout à fait correcte.

Comment: Oui, je sais qu'on peut utiliser le subjonctif dans d'autres phrases où on n'a pas besoin d'un "un". Je veux juste savoir pour le cas si on utilise de verbes de recherche...

Comment: Vous n'utilisez pas le subjonctif après pour que, bien que, il est important que... à l'oral?

Comment: le subjonctif n'a pas vraiment d'exception, on peut l'utiliser avec n'importe quel type de verbe : rechercher, aimer, savoir, ... toutes les formes sont correctes, et se rapprochent souvent du présent de l'indicatif à l'oral (mais attention à l'écrit, l'accord est différent) ....................... PS: excuse-moi pour l'erreur, j'avais mal tourné ma phrase :/