# Can I use the subjunctive without the « que »?

Tags: subjonctif

I've been told that a general rule is that the subjunctive always follows a « que » but are there instances where I can use it without that « que » just to express general doubt? For example, could I use the subjunctive in a sentence like « Elle est peut-être la seule personne qui puisse nous aider »?

Comment: Contre-exemples : "Puisse-t-elle nous aider !" (May she help us!) ; "Ainsi soit-il" (So be it).

Comment: [See also](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/31147/358)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you would need another relative pronoun or conjunction.  Both *que* and *qui* can be used as relative pronouns.  What invokes the subjunctive makes the difference, as many phrases are impersonal, using *que* as a subordinating conjunction.  For simplicity's sake, all these examples are sentences that use the subjunctive after the relative pronoun *que* or *qui* or the subordinating conjunction *que* (like in *il faut que*).

**Que** is used when the subjects of the clauses are different.

> Il est temps que tu te taises.  (Il ≠ tu, *que* as subordinating conjunction) 
> C'est le meilleur film que j'aie vu. (le film ≠ je, *que* est un pronom relatif)

**Qui** is used when the subject is the same as the relative proposition.  Your example is perfect when the *qui* means *tel que* or *telle que.*  Note that the indicative or conditional can work with some contexts, as it's more current, and it depends on what you mean.

> Elle est la seule personne qui puisse nous aider. (Elle = qui)
>
> Je cherche quelqu'un qui sache parler français. (quelqu'un = qui)

**Dont** also works with superlatives that invoke the subjunctive like *le seul dont*

> De mes cousins, je suis la seule **dont** les yeux soient bruns.

[BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=5168) for reference.

Comment: Could you quickly just give me an example with « dont »? I'm finding it hard to conceptualise.

Comment: 1/ In "il faut que" the word "que" is not a relative pronoun but the conjunction "que". 2/  When "que" is a relative, you do not use it when the subjects are different (which is not at all a grammatical criterion in this case), but you use "que" as the _object_ pronoun and "qui" as the subject pronoun. Your examples are correct sentences, but there are serious flaws in your grammar. It would be well to fix that.

Comment: @None and LPH Duly noted with the impersonal phrases; *que* is a subordinating conjunction.  I oversimplified, focused on the *qui* au lieu de *que* et j'ai perdu le fil du brouillon.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the subjunctive follows the form "que" very often. But this is not the sole possibility. Essentially, it is used after certain locutions (ending with "que", but "que" is not parsed as a word then), in certain fixed expressions, and after relative pronouns.

A general reference on the French subjunctive is this [article from the BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=subjonctif).

Here follow certain parts of it relative to where the use of this mood is required.

> ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4236)) Les emplois du subjonctif sont nombreux. Dans la majorité de ses emplois, le subjonctif apparaît dans une proposition subordonnée, d’où son nom sub-jonctif, du latin subjungere, qui signifie « subordonner, mettre sous la dépendance de ». On le trouve notamment dans des subordonnées introduites par un verbe qui exprime le doute, l’incertitude, la crainte, la supposition, l’éventualité, le regret, le souhait, la nécessité, etc.

[Subjonctif après certaines locutions conjonctives](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4238)
[Subjonctif dans certaines expressions figées](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4252)

> [Subjonctif et proposition relative](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5168))
>
> Dans les cas où la subordonnée est une proposition relative introduite par que (aussi appelée subordonnée relative en nouvelle grammaire), on emploie généralement l’indicatif. Toutefois, l’emploi du subjonctif est aussi possible, selon le sens de la phrase.
>
> Si la proposition principale est négative, interrogative ou hypothétique, la proposition relative est normalement au subjonctif.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - Il n’y a que cette proposition qui soit acceptable.
> - En connaissez-vous d’autres qui aient la même compétence?
>
> Lorsque la proposition relative comporte le sens de « tel que », elle peut se construire avec le subjonctif. L’indicatif (y compris le conditionnel) reste toutefois possible.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - Nous sommes à la recherche d’une personne qui sache se servir d’un tableur.
> - (c’est-à-dire : Nous sommes à la recherche d’une personne telle qu’elle sache se servir d’un tableur.)
> - Nous sommes à la recherche d’une personne qui sait se servir d’un tableur.
> - Nous sommes à la recherche d’une personne qui saurait se servir d’un tableur.
>
> Il y a des contextes où le subjonctif, le futur et le présent de l’indicatif ainsi que le conditionnel peuvent s’employer, avec des nuances de sens indiquant une plus ou moins grande éventualité dans la réalisation de l’action.
> Exemples :
>
> - Choisissez un appareil qui pourrait s’installer facilement. (conditionnel)
> - Choisissez un appareil qui puisse s’installer facilement. (présent du subjonctif)
> - Choisissez un appareil qui pourra s’installer facilement. (futur de l’indicatif)
> - Choisissez un appareil qui peut s’installer facilement. (présent de l’indicatif)
>
> On emploie plus souvent le subjonctif que l’indicatif après un superlatif ou l’équivalent d’un superlatif, notamment *le seul (la seule) qui, le seul que, le seul dont, l’unique qui, le premier qui, le dernier que, le meilleur que*, ainsi qu’après *il n’y a que… qui (que, dont, etc.)* et *il y a peu de… que*.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - C’est le seul ordinateur qui nous convienne.
> - Il s’agit de la première imprimante qui soit dotée de cette fonction.
> - Voilà le meilleur rapport que j’aie lu.
> - Il n’y a que cette solution qui puisse les satisfaire.